# Get key usage using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way to get a list of keys and count their values using `pymongo`? I have solved it using `Counter` object and looping through the entire collection, however, this code would be inefficient for extensive collections. Is there a way how to solve it on the database level?

```
import pymongo
from collections import Counter
client = pymongo.MongoClient("XXX")
database = client["jiripesik"]
collection = database["database"]
result = collection.find({})
key_list = []
for item in result:
    for key in item.keys():
        key_list.append(key)
counter = Counter(key_list)
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this would be very performant, but here's a way to get a count of all the top-level fields in the collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "keys": {
        "$map": {
          "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
          "in": "$$this.k"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$keys" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$keys",
      "count": { "$count": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "histo": {
        "$mergeObjects": {
          "$arrayToObject": [
            [ { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$replaceWith": "$histo" }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QCx_4ecipM4).